# OWL 2 Reasoners and custom datatypes not working

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I am trying to run the Protege Reasoner, there are two reasoner available Fact++ and HermiT 1.3.7.

I tried to run the both but their is window comes and suddenly goes. It's difficult to see that one so I use the screen recorder to get that but it doesn't contain any information.
[image]

There is no error message or log message I can found.

The reasoner is not being started.

I tried to use the option Export inferred axioms as ontology and then I get the expected error message "No Reasoner intialized"

Please suggest.

EDIT 1:

Error log due to the new data type defined:

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.ReasonerInternalException: Unsupported datatype
'http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/6/untitled-ontology-6#perce
ntage'
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.FaCTPlusPlus.getBuiltInDataType(Nati
ve Method)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.toData
TypePointer(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner$AxiomT
ranslator$DeclarationVisitorEx.visit(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner$AxiomT
ranslator$DeclarationVisitorEx.visit(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDatatypeImpl.accept(OWLDatatypeImpl
.java:338)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner$AxiomT
ranslator.visit(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner$AxiomT
ranslator.visit(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDeclarationAxiomImpl.accept(OWLDecl
arationAxiomImpl.java:128)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.loadAx
iom(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.loadRe
asonerAxioms(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.<init>
(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasonerFactory
.createReasoner(Unknown Source)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.owlapiv3.FaCTPlusPlusReasonerFactory
.createReasoner(Unknown Source)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.ReasonerUtilities.createReason
er(ReasonerUtilities.java:21)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$Classif
icationRunner.ensureRunningReasonerInitialized(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:398)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$Classif
icationRunner.run(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:354)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Ontology in use:

http://pastebin.com/L0heDLBy

Comment: Did you select a reasoner from the reasoner menu?

Comment: There is option to define the new Data types and I found a interesting fact that we add new some new Data Types like percentage, we can't use the Fact++ Reasoner and also in some other cases the Fact++ Reasoner is not working I found the HermiT 1.3.7 is working though now for me. Thanks.

Comment: Extra datatypes are not supported by FaCT++ at present - it should probably just ignore them rather than throwing an error

Comment: The Reasoner Progress window is an indication that the reasoner is being started. There might be a stack trace available in the top left corner, where a red triangle should show up. Otherwise, try starting Protege from a console (run the run.bat file in the protege main folder) and see if any message is printed there. Can you share the ontology, or replicate the problem on a publicly available ontology?

Comment: @Ignazio I have added the Error log message and the pastebin link for the ontology.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace confirms that FaCT++ does not allow custom datatypes to be specified - this is currently a known limitation. I don't know about HermiT but there's a good chance the problem is the same.

Pellet used to have more flexible datatype treatment, you can try installing it and use it instead of HermiT or FaCT++